# Difference of create Index by using include column or not using

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I Want To Create Index In SQL Server 2008 R2 in Column1 and Column2
What is the difference of below query:

1. Not include

   ```
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_1] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
   (
       [Column1] ASC,
       [Column2] ASC
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   ```
2. Or include:

   ```
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_2] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
   (
       [Column1] ASC
   )
   INCLUDE ([Column2]) ON [PRIMARY]
   ```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the first one `Column2` gets added to the index key. In the second one it might not <sup>(*)</sup> get added to the key in which case it will only appear in the index leaf pages. This can allow the index to be searched by `Column1` but avoid the need to go back to the base table ([bookmark lookup/key lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820714/what-is-a-bookmark-lookup-in-sql-server)) to retrieve the value for `Column2`.

i.e. it makes index2 "covering" for queries such as

```
SELECT Column1,Column2
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] 
WHERE Column1 = 'X'
```

And it also covers queries such as

```
SELECT Column1,Column2
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] 
WHERE Column1 = 'X' AND Column2 = 'Y'
```

But index1 may well perform better for the second query as it can seek on the two columns directly (as opposed to only being able to search on `Column1` then needing to evaluate all matching rows at the index leaf level to see if they meet the `Column2` predicate). If `Column2` is never used as a search predicate against that index and your queries against that index wouldn't benefit from having `Column2` ordered then it should be added as an `INCLUDE`-d column to keep the size of the key down and reduce the number of pages in the index.

<sub>(*) The reason I say "might not" above is because if `Column2` is (part of) the clustered index key it [will still be added there anyway](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/03/07/more-about-nonclustered-index-keys.aspx) for a non clustered index not created with the `UNIQUE` option.</sub>

Comment: Very useful answer