# SQL Server: multi-column index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference of create Index by using include column or not using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828568/difference-of-create-index-by-using-include-column-or-not-using)

**Edit: IGNORE THIS POST, I flagged it for a mod as it's a duplicate. Thanks all for the replies!**

Creating multi-column indexes, what's the difference between these two:

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex ON TABLE1 (COLUMN1 ASC, COLUMN2 ASC, COLUMN3 ASC, [etc...])
```

vs.

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex ON TABLE1 (COLUMN1 ASC)
INCLUDE (COLUMN2, COLUMN3, [etc...] )
```

MSDN says that the latter means including nonkey columns. What does this mean in layman's terms? Point being, I'm basically dealing with a situation where I have to optimize queries that only need data from 3-5 columns out of dozens within the table, using one of the columns as the "base" index so to speak and getting the other column values from the same row.

Creating a clustered index on the one is not an option as the table is updated regularly, which tends to create a lot of locks and waits. I'm currently testing these out but I'd like an informed answer from you guys too. :)

Comment: This question might be a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah right it is a duplicate, thanks. That page has exactly the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the index isn't based on the columns in the INCLUDE clause, which means that when a column in the INCLUDE clause is updated, the corresponding row within the index doesn't have to be moved.  For details, including usage scenarios, see [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/72276/)

Comment: Thanks Martin, my wording was inprecise - I've fixed it